# Dropdown menu automatically closes on clicking in selectize.js

Tags: angularjs, selectize.js

I want to use **selectize.js** in my project. Everything works fine except one thing, when I click on a scroll-bar in drop-down menu it closes automatically and I don't understand how to fix this issue, maybe I should do something in config. Someone faced with this problem?

Here is my config object:

```
facility_config = {
                maxItems: 1,
                plugins: ['remove_button'],
                valueField: 'id',
                searchField: ['facility_name'],
                optgroups: [
                    { id: 0, group_name: 'Teams' },
                    { id: 1, group_name: 'Primary Practices' },
                    { id: 2, group_name: 'Facility Affiliations' }
                ],
                optgroupField: 'group_name',
                optgroupValueField: 'group_name',
                optgroupLabelField: 'group_name',
                lockOptgroupOrder: true,
                render: {
                    item: function (item, escape) {
                        return '<div class="option">' +
                        '<span>' + escape(item.facility_name) + '</span>' +
                        '<span ng-if="item.city && item.state">' + ' ( ' + escape(item.city) + ', ' + escape(item.state) + ' )' + '</span>' +
                        '<span class="fa fa-asterisk text-orange"></span>'
                        '</div>';
                    },
                    optgroup_header: function (data, escape) {
                        return '<div class="optgroup-header"><strong>' + escape(data.group_name) + '</strong></div>';
                    },
                    option: function (item, escape) {
                        return '<div class="option">' +
                               '<span>' + escape(item.facility_name) + '</span>' +
                               '<span ng-if="item.city && item.state" class="text-muted">' + ' ( ' + escape(item.city) + ', ' + escape(item.state) + ' )' + '</span>' +
                               '<span class="fa fa-asterisk text-orange"></span>'
                               '</div>';
                    }
                }
            };
```

And my html:

```
<selectize options="model.items", config="model.facility_config", ng-model="modalObject.facility_id"></selectize>
```

sample data can be as :

```
items = [{id: 1, facility_name: 'QA', state: 'LA', city: 'San Francisco', group_name: 'Teams'}];
```

Comment: can you add a jsfiddle with your code in it ? It will help to solve your issue, Thanks.

Comment: can you add some sample data (model.items) ?

Comment: i've tried to put this config in a plnkr, but it seems working, check it out http://plnkr.co/edit/rVHX3lZ77pQWBAeGNaNn

Comment: Thank you. I also checked in a plnkr, everything works, but in my project I have this problem and I don't understand why it happens.

Comment: are you using the same version in the plnkr ?